# Printing sms using huawei_lte_api

Tags: python, sms, huawei-mobile-services

My code:

```
from huawei_lte_api.Client import Client
from huawei_lte_api.Connection import Connection

with Connection('http://admin:admin@192.168.8.1/') as connection:
    client = Client(connection) 
    sms_list = client.sms.get_sms_list()
    print(sms_list)
```

Result:

{'Count': '6', 'Messages': {'Message': [{'Smstat': '0', 'Index': '40006', 'Phone': 'Ufone', 'Content': 'SMS failed.', 'Date': '2023-03-11 01:21:12', 'Sca': None, 'SaveType': '4', 'Priority': '0', 'SmsType': '1'}, {'Smstat': '0', 'Index': '40005', 'Phone': 'Ufone', 'Content': 'SMS failed.', 'Date': '2023-03-11 01:21:06', 'Sca': None, 'SaveType': '4', 'Priority': '0', 'SmsType': '1'}, {'Smstat': '0', 'Index': '40004', 'Phone': 'Ufone', 'Content': 'SMS failed.', 'Date': '2023-03-11 01:21:00', 'Sca': None, 'SaveType': '4', 'Priority': '0', 'SmsType': '1'}, {'Smstat': '0', 'Index': '40003', 'Phone': 'Ufone', 'Content': 'SMS failed due.', 'Date': '2023-03-11 01:20:55', 'Sca': None, 'SaveType': '4', 'Priority': '0', 'SmsType': '1'}, {'Smstat': '0', 'Index': '40002', 'Phone': 'Ufone', 'Content': 'SMS failed .', 'Date': '2023-03-11 01:20:50', 'Sca': None, 'SaveType': '4', 'Priority': '0', 'SmsType': '1'}, {'Smstat': '0', 'Index': '40001', 'Phone': 'Ufone', 'Content': 'SMS failed.', 'Date': '2023-03-11 01:20:44', 'Sca': None, 'SaveType': '4', 'Priority': '0', 'SmsType': '1'}]}}

Desired Result

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1Dah.png)

Thanks in advance

success reading sms from Huawei modem using huawei-lte-api.

Now i want to arrange results in tabular form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas to get it into a table easily.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [{'Smstat': '0', 'Index': '40006', 'Phone': 'Ufone', 'Content': 'SMS failed.', 'Date': '2023-03-11 01:21:12', 'Sca': None, 'SaveType': '4', 'Priority': '0', 'SmsType': '1'}, {'Smstat': '0', 'Index': '40005', 'Phone': 'Ufone', 'Content': 'SMS failed.', 'Date': '2023-03-11 01:21:06', 'Sca': None, 'SaveType': '4', 'Priority': '0', 'SmsType': '1'}, {'Smstat': '0', 'Index': '40004', 'Phone': 'Ufone', 'Content': 'SMS failed.', 'Date': '2023-03-11 01:21:00', 'Sca': None, 'SaveType': '4', 'Priority': '0', 'SmsType': '1'}, {'Smstat': '0', 'Index': '40003', 'Phone': 'Ufone', 'Content': 'SMS failed due.', 'Date': '2023-03-11 01:20:55', 'Sca': None, 'SaveType': '4', 'Priority': '0', 'SmsType': '1'}, {'Smstat': '0', 'Index': '40002', 'Phone': 'Ufone', 'Content': 'SMS failed .', 'Date': '2023-03-11 01:20:50', 'Sca': None, 'SaveType': '4', 'Priority': '0', 'SmsType': '1'}, {'Smstat': '0', 'Index': '40001', 'Phone': 'Ufone', 'Content': 'SMS failed.', 'Date': '2023-03-11 01:20:44', 'Sca': None, 'SaveType': '4', 'Priority': '0', 'SmsType': '1'}]
table = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(table)
```

To get this you can do:

```
table = pd.DataFrame(sms_list['Messages']['Message'])
print(table)
```

and that would be your data.
[image: Result of print]

Comment: Mustafa, thank you for your response. How to automatically strip this part "{'Count': '6', 'Messages': {'Message':" and last two curly brackets. Keep in mind 6 could be any number 6 or 60 or 600...

Comment: so the first part of what I explained is what you do when the data isn't stripped. sms_list['Messages']['Message'] strips the parts you don't want when making the table. You can print(sms_list['Messages']['Message']) and it'll show what I mean.